# PageSpeed Insights doesn't recognize WebP format when using jpg fallback

Tags: seo, pagespeed-insights

I'm trying to get rid of the message "Serve Images in Next-Gen Formats" in PageSpeed Insights (PSI). In order to do that, I'm changing all HTML code of the images to:

```
<picture>
  <source type="image/webp" srcset="imgwebpversion.webp">
  <source type="image/jpeg" srcset="imgjpegversion.jpg">
  <img src="imgjpegversion.jpg" alt="alt description here" width="200" height="56">
</picture>
```

But PSI keeps on showing the message. Does anyone know what's the correct approach to serve webp  images and still support old browsers?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Can you share the link?

Comment: Sure: https://www.fisicalab.com/exp/cwv/angulos

Comment: Strange. Lighthouse isn't reporting it, so maybe it's safe to ignore that one.

Comment: Yes, lighthouse isn't reporting any issue with next gen formats. In fact, if you change all of the <picture> tags with jpeg's or png's <img> tags, lighthouse doesn't report anything either. Anyway, PSI does report it: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=en&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.fisicalab.com%2Fexp%2Fcwv%2Fangulos

Comment: Anyway... no one has an answer?

Comment: Mine is you're doing it fine and PSI is broken.

Comment: It's "funny" as Google push us, the publishers, to move forward with this new formats in their core web vitals update but they provide some tools that may confuse us and make us waste our time...